# nuxt vue router afterEach guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I set an afterEach handler that executes after route changes in nuxt? The middleware can be used as an beforeEach, but I could not find a way to implement the afterEach hook.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can create a plugin like the following:

```
// plugins/after-each.js:
export default async ({ app }) => {

  app.router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    // Do something
  });

}
```

And then reference it in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
plugins: [ { src: '~/plugins/after-each.js', mode: 'client' } ]
```

*Note: Since Nuxt.js 2.4, `mode` has been introduced as option of `plugins` to specify plugin type, possible value are: `client` or `server`. `ssr: false` will be adapted to `mode: 'client'` and deprecated in next major release.*